# How to feed data as a preserved info in open AI chat-completions?

Tags: openai-api, chatgpt-api

Using [OpenAI chat-completions-api](https://platform.openai.com/docs/guides/gpt/chat-completions-api), I want to create a software that can preserve some data, as the augmented knowledge to reproduce the text. I do not simply mean a chat history, but a data structure of my specific entity like a json data or a returned query of a Database. I need to use these info as the `user message` but the message is limited, and of course I do not know how much data I might have. As an example of what I want, suppose we have an Employee system and each employee has its specific data such as name, years of experience, the role they have in a company, salary etc. So, according to all these info and background I want my software to be able to create a suitable response to the questions.

Is it possible to do?
the simple request as it is found in the documentation is as follows:

```
curl https://api.openai.com/v1/chat/completions \
  -H "Content-Type: application/json" \
  -H "Authorization: Bearer $OPENAI_API_KEY" \
  -d '{
    "model": "gpt-3.5-turbo",
    "messages": [{"role": "system", "content": "You are a helpful assistant."}, {"role": "user", "content": "Hello!"}]
  }'
```

Comment: That request is for `completions` not `chatCompletions`